# Performance loss with gcc linker optimization flag -flto

Tags: gcc, optimization, linker, arm, linker-flags

I am working on a ARM Cortex A15 and using GCC compile (actually integrating it with TI's SYS/BIOS using XDC tools...)

After I enable -ftlo flag, I am having a performance loss about %30, which is a significant value. I am doing simple benchmark tests like pi and prime number calculating and also system dependent procedural tests.

Below are my compile and link flags. Is this amount of downgrade possible without any errors? Is there a possible cause for this? From what I searched through the internet, I come across benchmarks that flto may not improve the performance but I didn't see such a performance loss...

```
# Compile options.
C_OPTS =    -w\
-mcpu=cortex-a15 \
-mtune=cortex-a15 \
-mabi=aapcs \
-mapcs \
-mfpu=neon \
-mfloat-abi=hard \
-O3 \
-flto \
-fno-strict-aliasing \
-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks \
-fno-strict-overflow \

# Linker options.
L_OPTS = -nostartfiles \
-static \
-Wl,--gc-sections \
-Wl,-Map,$(BUILD_DIR)/$(NAME).map \
-mfloat-abi=hard \
-e wbcd_ep \
-flto \
-fuse-linker-plugin \
```

Comment: This has been asked before.  Gcc version is important.  Telling GCC what L1/L2 cache size is also important.  The linker you use is important.  You should pass the linker an `-O3` option so that the **LTO** optimizer will optimize.  Ie. `L_OPTS += -O3`.  It makes sense to use the same optimizer settings for the compile and the *link compile*; so you can use a common make variable for both, like `-fno-strict-overflow`, etc.

Comment: I tried that. Stragenly, one of the projects do not wait in the main at the startup. I can't understand the problem, I can assumpt that the generated code is broken somehow. Another project runs but there is no performance gain. At least no performance loss too.

Comment: `-O3` is dangerous. There will be some hard-to-understand optimization passes in `-O3`. If you are not very very expert in C, don't use it.